# awk not being recognized after certain command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Here's a MWE:

```
#!/bin/bash
INFILE=$1
echo `echo $INFILE | awk '{print(substr($0,8,3))}'`

PATH=${INFILE%/*}
echo `echo $INFILE | awk '{print(substr($0,8,3))}'`
exit
```

Apparently the first `awk`command runs fine, but in the second command `bash` doesn't recognize `awk`anymore!
This is what I get running it (assuming that `f_mwe.sh` is the name of the file):

```
$ ./f_mwe.sh /home/something/path/this_is_the_name.txt
ome
./f_mwe.sh: line 31: awk: command not found

$
```

I have tried defining `/bin/sh` and `ksh` at the beginning also but got the same results. I have no idea what's causing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use of `ALL_CAPS` variables is generally discouraged as they are "reserved" for shell/internal use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the PATH variable and not appending to it I believe.  You should append to the PATH variable.

Comment: THE PATH! I completely forgot that `$PATH` was an already defined variable! What an idiot mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Fresh set of eyes never hurt anyone.  Happy Programming!